# Display a different div based on the combination of two different options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

OK, so I am trying to display a different iFrame (in a div) based on the selection of two different options. The first option is BOYS or GIRLS, and the second option is GRADE LEVEL. With 1st-12th, that would be 24 total divs.

Upon load, I'd want the BOYS option and 12th Grade option chosen and the corresponding div displaying that particular iframe. The following code is merely my attempt to display how I want the sidebar of choices to look. Functionally, I'm not sure if much of it applies.

Thank you for any help you're willing and able to provide. I've been searching a few hours a day over the past few days with no luck.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#radio" ).buttonset();
  });
  </script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#radiox" ).buttonset();
  });
  </script>
<style>
body {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Helvetica", "Arial",  "Verdana", "sans-serif";
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
.radioA label [
width:250px;
]
</style>
<form>
  <div id="radio">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" checked="checked"><label for="radio1" style="width:100px;">BOYS</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio"><label for="radio2" style="width:100px;">GIRLS</label>
  </div>
</form>
<br>
<form>
  <div id="radiox">
    <input type="radio" id="radioA" name="radio" checked="checked"><label for="radioA" style="width:100px;">12th Grade</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radioB" name="radio"><label for="radioB" style="width:100px;">11th Grade</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="radioC" name="radio"><label for="radioC" style="width:100px;">10th Grade</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radioD" name="radio"><label for="radioD" style="width:100px;">9th Grade</label><br>  
    <input type="radio" id="radioE" name="radio"><label for="radioE" style="width:100px;">8th Grade</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radioF" name="radio"><label for="radioF" style="width:100px;">7th Grade</label><br>  
    <input type="radio" id="radioG" name="radio"><label for="radioG" style="width:100px;">6th Grade</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radioH" name="radio"><label for="radioH" style="width:100px;">5th Grade</label><br>  
    <input type="radio" id="radioI" name="radio"><label for="radioI" style="width:100px;">4th Grade</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radioJ" name="radio"><label for="radioJ" style="width:100px;">3rd Grade</label><br>  
    <input type="radio" id="radioK" name="radio"><label for="radioK" style="width:100px;">2nd Grade</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radioL" name="radio"><label for="radioL" style="width:100px;">1st Grade</label><br>  
    <input type="radio" id="radioM" name="radio"><label for="radioM" style="width:100px;">7 Year Olds</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radioN" name="radio"><label for="radioN" style="width:100px;">6 Year Olds</label><br>  
    <input type="radio" id="radioO" name="radio"><label for="radioO" style="width:100px;">5 Year Olds</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radioP" name="radio"><label for="radioP" style="width:100px;">4 Year Olds</label><br>  
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Don't want to be rude but this sounds like a homework problem. If so, you need to try to implement the solution (try doing something with the input to get you there) in some sort of way before asking for help.

Comment: No, not homework. I have a website for basketball, and am trying to do this. I don't know how to do it whatsoever. Is this the kind of site to go to, or is this information privileged knowledge? I've seen a few questions similar to mine answered on this very site, but nothing that I can use. I have no clue of where to even start. I was thinking there might be a way to add two classes together to produce an array of results, but again... I have no clue where to start. If this is impossible, let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer & Demo

If I understood correctly you want to display a different `iframe` url for each radio combination. So that's what I did in this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7j5c0fzv/4/), although abstracted and with less, much less content (you should be able to expand on it).

### HTML

```
<form>
    <h1>Gender:</h1>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="boys" checked/>Boys<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="girls"/>Girls<br/>
    <h1>Grades:</h1>
    <input type="radio" name="grade" value="1" checked/>1st Grade<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="grade" value="2" />2nd Grade<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="grade" value="3" />3rd Grade<br/>
</form>
<br>
<div>
    <iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
</div>
```

It's pretty straight forward, although I think you messed up with the radio's name attribute there. The name is what defines the group of radious together, naming a radio: "radio" would be redundant :)

### JavaScript

```
window.onload = init;
function init(){
    iframe = document.querySelector("#iframe");
    radios = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]");
    for( var i = 0 ; i < radios.length ; i ++ ){
        var radio = radios[i];
        radio.onchange = updateIframeSrc;
    }
    updateIframeSrc();   
}

function updateIframeSrc(){
    var gender = document.querySelector("input[name=gender]:checked").value;
    var grade = document.querySelector("input[name=grade]:checked").value;
    var url;
    switch(gender){
        case "boys":
            switch(grade){
                case "1":
                    url = "http://www.boysgrade1.com";
                    break;
                case "2":
                    url = "http://www.boysgrade2.com";
                    break;
                case "3":
                    url = "http://www.boysgrade3.com";
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case "girls":
            switch(grade){
                case "1":
                    url = "http://www.girlsgrade1.com";
                    break;
                case "2":
                    url = "http://www.girlsgrade2.com";
                    break;
                case "3":
                    url = "http://www.girlsgrade3.com";
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
    iframe.src = url;
}
```

### Explanation

I'm a little tired (3 a.m) so I'll make it quick, basicly all the magic happens in the `updateIframeSrc()` function, which is called when the page loads, and then every time an `input radio` changes.

First, using css query selectors, we get the gender `value` from an `input` with `name=gender` that is `checked`.

Then, we get the grade `value` from an `input` with `name=grade` that is `checked`.

Since you want a custom url for each combination, I'm afraid it's going to be tedious, and you'll have to use the switch syntax.

To later add a grade, you should append a new case to the corresponding switch:

```
switch(gender){
    (..)
    case "girls":
        switch(grade){
            (..)
            case "graduated":
                url = "http://graduatedstudents.com";
                break;
        }
        break;
}
```

And don't forget to add the corresponding html syntax!

```
<input type="radio" name="grade" value="graduated" />Graduated Student<br/>
```

Hopes this helps! I'm going to sleep, see you :)

### Updates

- Updated code to call `updateIframeSrc()` on `input radio` change. (*3:29a.m 31/12/2014*)
- Updated code to assign a custom `iframe src` url for each `input radio` combination. (*3:58a.m 31/12/14*)

Comment: This is great! Is there a way to do this with an onclick option instead... like without having to press 'send'? THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Comment: And I would also need for the URL's to be completely different. I don't have access to PHP, nor am I versed in it. I was thinking of displaying a div that would hold various iframes. Is that possible? Thank you so much. Take as much time as you want to reply. I truly appreciate you time, energy, and attention.

Comment: Well I can't sleep anyway, yes, there is an onclick option instead.  The iframe's in the div, it can be done (is not very efficient, but it can), but I still need to get an idea of how the urls should be, could you give me an example?

Comment: You're awesome. It would be BOYS and GIRLS, with 16 different grade apiece. So 32 completely different URLS. Well, they'd be different ranges within the same Google Spreadsheet... but nothing that could just replace the suffix.

Comment: Spreadsheet URLS look and differ like this: 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EmCaG5CMlhoMfc0Jng1LrgDKALulRnFoLkDf4vgPU88/pubhtml?widget=false&amp;headers=false&gid=858471481&range=Q101:V120&chrome=false

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EmCaG5CMlhoMfc0Jng1LrgDKALulRnFoLkDf4vgPU88/pubhtml?widget=false&amp;headers=false&gid=858471481&range=Q121:V140&chrome=false

Comment: So the url's themselves wouldn't be related at all with gender and grade? Like for gender boys and grade 1 it would be url "icanshowyoutheworld.com"?

Comment: NO. So I'm guessing that's the hard part. I've seen scripts that show whatever divs you'd need, and that seems like what I need. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: It's not **that** hard, but it's going to be a little tedious, I've updated the answer to hopefully fullfill all your intentions, now I'm really going to sleep, if you have further questions I'll see them tomorrow (today at a reasonable hour). So, good luck man! :) (ps:If you feel this post answered your question click the green tick besides the answer, thanks!)

Comment: Works impeccably. I get exactly what I need to do from here. Thank you so much. I'll mark as solved, will try to get you some points, and please inbox me with your paypal so I can buy you a drink!

Comment: Thanks man, there is no need for a drink, your appreciation is enough :) (Also there is no inbox so if you still need something comment here or ask another question) Glad it works, bye :)